# MS Access to MySQL Conversion help (Gigantic table)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, export

So I have this gigantic table, containing approx 7 million records, in MS Access (*.mdb), I want to transfer it into a much more workable MySQL format, and store it on my webserver. The file itself weighs 2GB.

The problem is, since the table is so large, it won't let me export it normally (Access says the limit is 65,536 records.)

I've tried some 3rd party software but to no avail.

Can anyone recommend a clean way of doing so, without damaging the data inside?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Perhaps try migrating to MS SQL Server first, and then to MySQL?

Comment: I don't have such as server, unfortunately...

Comment: There you go: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Comment: I'm afraid 78MB is a bit too much for my cellphone-powered shaky connection. Will try it when I get home, thanks for the help.

Comment: What method are you using to export it? A 65,536 limit doesn't strike me as a limitation that applies to every export method available.

Comment: I tried both the excel export and the text file export. Both tell me that I cannot export more then 65,536.

Comment: Excel before 2007 would have that limit, but a text file shouldn't. Odd. Buy why are you exporting to an intermediate format in the first place? Why not export directly to MySQL?

Comment: @David how would I do that? That's kinda the question. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install an ODBC driver for MySQL, if you don't have one already.  The latest version is available here: [Download Connector/ODBC](http://www.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/)

Create a DSN (Data Source Name) for your MySQL server from the Windows ODBC Data Source Administrator.

Then from Access 2003, select your table in the Database Window, and choose File->Export from Access' main menu.  In the "Export Table '*yourtablename*' To ..." dialog, select "ODBC Databases()" from the "Save as type" drop-down list (at the bottom of the dialog).  The next dialog allows you to specify the name MySQL will use for the exported table, and it defaults to the Access table name.  After you click OK, you will get another dialog, "Select Data Source", where you can select your DSN for MySQL.  After you click OK on that dialog, you will probably get one more asking you for user name and password.  Supply them, and click OK.

Hopefully your table will then transfer without errors.  However, I've never done that operation with MySQL.  It has worked for me with ODBC transfers to SQL Server and PostGreSQL.  So I don't see why it wouldn't work with MySQL, too.

Also I've never attempted to export 7 million records in one go.  If it chokes, we'll have to figure out a work-around.

If you're using Access 2007 instead of 2003, look for a similar option starting with the Export section of the ribbon.

I suggested this approach because my impression is this export will be a one-time deal, so I think the Access UI export method would be easiest.  However, you can do essentially the same operation with VBA code using the [DoCmd.TransferDatabase Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb214131%28office.12%29.aspx) with your ODBC DSN.

Yet another alternative would be to create a compatible table structure in MySQL, create a link in Access to the MySQL destination table (using your DSN again), then run an "append query" from Access:

```
INSERT INTO link_to_mysql_table (field1, field2, field3, etc)
SELECT field1, field2, field3, etc
FROM access_table;
```

The append query approach could be useful in case the export chokes on 7 million records.  You could add a WHERE clause to limit the SELECT query's output record set to a manageable chunk size, and then repeat with a different WHERE to specify another chunk.

Comment: I'm using ACCESS 2010, I'll try to implement your solution on that, if you find a way please do tell.

Comment: Well, it started exporting and no errors yet! so I'm optimistic! This might just be it!! It choked alright, but heck, let it run all night, I'm doing this one time and that it

Comment: Awww it failed. Too large or not enough temporary space on the disk (2GB max). Will try your second method

Comment: Nuts!  By second method, did you mean an append query with a WHERE clause to restrict the number of rows transferred?  That's the one I would try next.

Comment: Yes. I also tried linking, no good. I'm currently trying to export it piece by piece (million by million tbe :P)

Comment: When I exported using the ODBC, the encoding was off, so any hebrew (yeah it's hebrew) text had become ?????. :(((

Comment: While it never actually worked, your solution seems like the correct one (only encoding issues that exists for all other methods as well). Also, it was the closest one to actually transfer the entire table (transferring 1 million at a time). Bounty is yours, great answer. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 1):

Is that 7 million value after a compact + repair? I mean, if each record is about 120 chars in length, you can fit 32 million records in 2 gigs.

Also, I not aware of a limit of exporting 65,000 records, but only in regards to Excel.

So, you can/should be able to export the data to a csv, and then use a bulk text import in mySql to pull that data in. So, try exporting the table as csv. That should work.

I mean, you could link a table via odbc if you have a good local connection to the sql server, but if not, then I would export to csv (it is  VERY fast). I would then zip the file (they zip fantastic).  Upload file to server, and un-zip, and then use bulk text import. So, such a zipped file is VERY small and will save huge amounts of transfer time.

You can also consider using tab delimited as mySql also can import those, but a simple text file should work just fine.

Comment: I have about 20 columns that describe each record. Though I can't say the table is 100% efficient (it wasn't me who made it). Also, the server is local, I'll try the CSV way and return to ya.

Comment: @David it does for me. Want the screenshot? (Maybe I'm doing it wrong, enlighten me).

Comment: How are you checking that it has that limitation? Are you opening the resulting CSV file in Excel? If so, Excel is the problem -- open it with Notepad and you'll see all the data there. I just exported a table with 7 million rows to a comma-delimited file.

Answer (score 1):

I would use pyodbc as described in

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Database_Programming

download python 2.7 from
http://python.org/
download 
http://code.google.com/p/pyodbc/

modify the following coede to set myfile.mdb and MyTable according to your table and file

save the code in a file translate.py

```
import csv
mycsv = csv.writer(open('result.csv', 'wb'), delimiter=',',
                    quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
import pyodbc

DBfile = 'myfile.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
cursor = conn.cursor()

SQL = 'SELECT * FROM MyTable;'
for row in cursor.execute(SQL): # cursors are iterable
    mycsv.writerow(row)

cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

run `python translate.py`

Comment: I'm afraid I don't program in python, I don't know what tools I need and I don't wish to start learning (yet).

Comment: Like I said, I don't intend on using Python for this job. If you have a PHP solution, I'll gladly test it.

Answer (score 0):

Install MySQL on your own system and upsize to it rather than trying to use your local server.  Then run an append query from your MySQL to the server instance.

Comment: I already have MySQL installed on my local machine, how do I transfer from ACCESS to it?

Comment: See the answer about ODBC driver for MySQL, etc, etc.   Although I'd likely create the table in the local copy of MySQL and link to it from inside Access.  Ensure there are no indexes on the MySQL table so it's as fast as possible.  Then run an append query from Access to the MySQL table.